# Is there a way to parameterize operator in c#

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say I have 2 handlers increment_click and decrement_click which calls common method

In real my method can be much more complex and I'd like to avoid to use syntax like with if

```
if (operator == "+") {
     return value = value + step
}
else {
     return value = value - step
}
```

and do something more generic like this

```
increment(value, operator, step) {
     return value = value <operator> step
}
```

Is it somehow possible ?

Comment: You could use enums for that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: An `enum` would still require a `switch` of `if` behind it.

Comment: On the calling side, is the "operator" value known at compile time?

Comment: whats wrong with the first syntax?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, Of course, but it will be only on function to handle it once for permanent use.

Comment: You could do this using Roslyn. You can get Roslyn to compile out a `Func<T, T, T>` from a `string.Format("return input1 {0} input2;" @operator)`.

Comment: I like Roslyn suggestion thanks though I've never thried roselyn yet

Comment: If the only operations are increment and decrement, then you can just pass an increment of -1 if you want to decrement. `increment(value, step) { return value + step; }`. For increment, pass +1. For decrement, pass -1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make a `Dictionary<string,Func<decimal,decimal,decimal>>` and set it up with implementations of your operators, like this:

```
private static readonly IDictionary<string,Func<decimal,decimal,decimal>> ops = new Dictionary<string,Func<decimal,decimal,decimal>> {
    {"+", (a,b) => a + b}
,   {"-", (a,b) => a - b}
,   {"*", (a,b) => a * b}
,   {"/", (a,b) => a / b}
};
```

Now you can do this:

```
decimal Calculate(string op, decimal a, decimal b) {
    return ops[op](a, b);
}
```

You can even do this generically with some "magic" from `Linq.Expressions`: instead of using pre-built lambdas defined in C#, you could define your lambdas programmatically, and compile them into `Func<T,T,T>`.

Comment: While I like the solution, it's not ***really*** an answer to the actual question - you're still doing a runtime resolve, so in essence it's just a rewritten `switch` statement this way. Kudos for creativity though, +1  :)

Comment: that answers my question though it's heavy weight :)

Answer (score 2):

I dont think this is much better but it's good option

```
int sign = (operator == "+" ? 1 : -1);
retrun value +sign*value;
```

Comment: Hehe the '??' typo resulted in this follow up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014079/how-to-use-c-sharp-for-this-expression I'll correct it in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what your entire use case is, but it seems a suitable scenario for employing delegates. Let's begin with defining a delegate:

```
public delegate T Operation<T>(T arg, T step);
```

and now let's assume you have a class with operators:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static Foo operator + (Foo left, Foo right) { ... } 
    public static Foo operator + (Foo left, Foo right) { ... } 
}
```

In the class where you want to handle the logic generically, you can use similar code:

```
public class Bar
{
    // The method you look for:
    public Foo Increment(Foo value, string @operator, Foo step)
    {
         Operation<Foo> operation = null;

         switch(@operator)
         {
             case "+":
                 operation = (v, s) => v + s;
                 break;
             case "-":
                 operation = (v, s) => v - s;
                 break;
             ...
         }

         if (operation != null)
         {
             return operation(value, step);
         }
         else
         {
             throw new NotSupportedException(
                 "Operator '" +  @operator "' is not supported");
         }
    }
}
```

In place of the `Foo` class that I used for clarity, you can use any of the primitive types in .NET that support these operations (`int`, `double`, `long`, etc).
Instead of defining your own delegate (like the `Operation<T>`, you can use the buil-in `Func<T, T>`.
I'd recommend using an enum instead of string for the operators (`+`, `-`, ...), since the string will allow for passing an invalid value.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only parametrize variables, and genericize types.