# How to use c# ?? for this expression

Tags: c#

Why does it say it cannot work with bool and int as for

```
int sign = (op == "+" ?? 1 : -1);
```

Do I need to use if ... then instead just to do that ?

Comment: +1 to undo -1 that you got - it's a reasonable question given that you can't easily search for "?" or "??"

Comment: @MackieChan But to elaborate on how one came to doing that would be interesting and potentially more educational in result, depending on the answerer. Coming along and asking "why is this hammer not working as a spanner?" without saying _why_ you're using a hammer to twist something is not very thoughtful.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) `?:`:

```
int sign = (op == "+" ? 1 : -1);
```

Double question marks is the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) which does an entirely different thing.

Answer (score 3):

That is invalid syntax.

The conditional operator uses a **single** `?`.

Answer (score 3):

Because the correct syntax is

```
int sign = (op == "+" ? 1 : -1);
```

with just one question mark.

The syntax with two question marks is used for the [Null Coalescing Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) while your  expression requires the [Conditional Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`??` is the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). `op == "?"` is an expression that returns a boolean value.

You're looking for `int sign = (op == "+" ? 1 : -1);`, which uses the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You only need one question mark for the conditional operator (also known as a ternary operator).

```
int sign = (op == "+" ? 1 : -1);
```

Comment: It's not "the ternary operator", it's *a* ternary operator. The correct name is "conditional operator".

Comment: It's C#'s only ternary operator, so "the ternary operator" isn't exactly wrong, but it's like referring to "the five letter operator" when you mean `await`.

Answer (score -1):

you should also check(depending on where does the string comes from) check if op
did get assign with some string

```
 string op = "+";
    int sign = ((op == "+") ? 1 : op.Length == 0? 0:-1);
```

EDIT:cheking for null option

```
int sign = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(op) ? 0 : (op == "+") ? 0 : -1);
```

Comment: And if it's null? This will npe, others won't.

Comment: in this case with the "+" it will get 1,if its another like "-" it will get -1,just in the case of null will get 0

Comment: If it's null `op.Length` is illegal, leading to `NullReferenceException`. You need to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(op)`

Comment: sorry,i didnt mean to say null(but you are right about your remark),what i mean is assuming you at least give empty value(string.empty) from the start,then depending on user interaction assigning it with a proper value,the string wont be null but lenght = 0 could happen.But of course if you dont assign anything then what you said in your comment is the best approach.